# Removing header in xml file required?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the xml file below and I want to retrieve the sym attribute from the Instrmt element using LINQ to XML.  In order to do that, do I have to remove the first line: FIXML element?

If I do that then the code below works:

```
IEnumerable<string> symbols = from c in xml.Descendants("Instrmt")
                              select (string)c.Attribute("Sym");
```

Here is the xml.

```
<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4 https://optionsclearing.com/components/docs/membership/dds_ref/fia_1_1/fixml-main-4-4-FIA-1-1.xsd">
  <Batch>
    <SecList ListTyp="109" ListID="20175" BizDt="2017-12-07">
      <SecL Ccy="USD">
       <Instrmt Desc="iShares S&amp;P 100 ETF" SecTyp="OPT" SubTyp="ETO" Sym="OEF" Mult="100.0">
         <AID AltID="00013" AltIDSrc="RBHP"/>
       </Instrmt>
       <InstrmtExt>
         <Attrb Typ="101" Val="1.0000"/>
         <Attrb Typ="108" Val="1.0000"/>
       </InstrmtExt>
       <Undly Desc="iShares S&amp;P 100 ETF" Px="117.110000" Ccy="USD" Sym="OEF" ID="464287101" Src="1"/>
       <Stip Typ="RBHMIN" Val="2.500"/>
       <Stip Typ="CPMMIN" Val="3.750"/>
      </SecL>
   </SecList>
  </Batch>
</FIXML>
```

Comment: Your code worked for me without removing the header, whats your problem?

Comment: I updated the original question with the header that's actually there.  This gives a 0 count for symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your problem is not about the header, it's about the namespace (defined by the xmlns attribute). As your xml define one, all your xml children elements will have it as their default. Try the following code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(pathToFile);
XNamespace ns = xml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
IEnumerable<string> symbols = from c in xml.Descendants(ns + "Instrmt")
                              select (string)c.Attribute("Sym");
```

Comment: Do you know of an article that explains why that needs to be done?

Comment: @rds80 Not an article, but you could google xml namespace. Bottom line, in a xml, you could have different authors that define the same Element name for different things and you could have a xml which uses both elements. So, to distinguish one from another, you define namespaces. When you don't specify a namespace for a element, it uses the default. When you define, all it's children will use it as their default, so you don't have to specify all over the document the same namespace.

Comment: As an update, I had to use the XMLTextReader, as the XDocument.Load was giving an out of memory exception error as the XML file was over a gig in size.